# excluding multiple IP address ranges from google analytics - trouble w/ regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

The regex expressions I'm entering into Google analytics are invalid and I'm hoping someone can help me figure them out. The ranges I want to exclude are:

```
192.168.0.1-100

192.168.100-200.100-200
```

The original statements I used are:

```
^192\.168\.0\.([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-9]|8[0-9]|9[0-9]|10[0-9])$

^192\.168\.(10[1-9]|11[0-9]|12[0-9]|13[0-9])|14[0-9]|15[0-9]|16[0-9]|17[0-9]|18[0-9]|19[0-9]|20[0])\.(10[1-9]|11[0-9]|12[0-9]|13[0-9]|14[0-9]|15[0-9]|16[0-9]|17[0-9]|18[0-9]|19[0-9]|20[0])$
```

If I select "that begins with" google saves the filters but my analytics aren't different from the non-filtered view of the site. If I select "that are equal to" google calls them invalid.

Some additional research showed me I could write the expressions as:

```
^192\.168\.0\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$

^192\.168\.(100\.(1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|((1(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])))|200\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|200))$
```

Unfortunately with the same results as my original statements. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can create a Custom filter that uses a "Filter Field" of "IP Address", and then your RegExes for the Filter Pattern. The patterns you are using would not work with a "Begins with" filter.

Comment: Thanks, I set-up custom filters. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your second regex is a bit wonky and will allow 200-250 in places, should be this instead:

```
^192\.168(\.(1[0-9][0-9]|200)){2}$
```

Note that because your third and fourth octets are the same we just used the parens and `{2}` to match two of them.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is ok, i have no idea about the second one, but this (in place of the second one) should work:

```
^192\.168(\.(1[0-9][0-9]|200)){2}$
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/yN1dD9/2

Comment: Thanks. Are the delimiters the ^ and $? I'll let the filters go for a couple days to see if they are working before editing again.

Comment: @Skky Nope, those are anchors, but i just noticed you are not actually using any delimiter, so nevermind :)